# jquery issue with show hide li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get an accordion like functionality, I have only `<li>`with classes .level1, .level2, .level3 ..etc, the issue I have is , if I click on .level2, items will hide until next .level2 element without issues. 
But if I click on .level3 and hide .level4, and then click .level2 to hide .level3, I can see .level4 item under .level2.

I don't know how to fix that

Please check demo:

```js
$('.level2').click(function(e) {

  if ($(this).next('li').hasClass('level3')) {
    $(this).nextUntil('.level2').toggle();
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})

$('.level3').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).next('li').hasClass('level4')) {

    $(this).nextUntil('.level3').toggle();
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})

$('.level4').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).next('li').hasClass('level5')) {

    $(this).nextUntil('.level4').toggle();
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="level1"><a href=""><span>Level1</a></li>
<li class="level2"><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
<li class="level2"><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level2"><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level2"><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
<li class="level3"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level4"><a href=""><span>Level4</a></li>
<li class="level2"><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I would wager a guess that you have `toggle()` under your `$('.level2').on(click...`.  It might be better to change that to `hide()` and have the `show()` as part of the click property for `$('.levelX')`

Comment: You need to call `e.preventDefault` outside the `if`. Otherwise, it follows the link and reloads the page.

Comment: thanks, but the issue isn't preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going about this in the wrong way if you're looking to toggle a structured menu of nested lists.  But assuming you DO want to have an arbitrary flat list, you need to check if the following item is visible and then explicitly call show() or hide().  For example:

```
$('.level2').click(function (e){
    toggleUntil(this, 'level3', 'level2');
    e.preventDefault();
})

$('.level3').click(function (e){  
    toggleUntil(this, 'level4', 'level3');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.level4').click(function (e){
    toggleUntil(this, 'level5', 'level4');
    e.preventDefault();
})

function toggleUntil(x, start, last) {
    if ($(x).next('li').hasClass(start)) {
         if ($(x).next('li').is(':visible')) {
             $(x).nextUntil('.' + last).hide();
         } else {
            $(x).nextUntil('.' + last).show();
         } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, Have a look on this, it might give you ideas of doing it cleaner and more efficient:

```js
$('li a').click(function (e){
  
    if($(this).parent().find('>ul').length>0){
       $(this).parent().find('>ul').toggle();
}
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href=""><span>Level1</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href=""><span>Level2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Level2</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Level2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Level3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

 </ul>
```